# Numbering the List of Figures and Table of Contents

Tags: table-of-contents, numbering

I would like to number the list of figures and the table of contents, with Roman numerals, themselves (not the things listed in them).

Doing this, while leaving the main text in **bold**, and leaving the number unformatted.

I can't seem to find a way of doing so.

Comment: This depends deliberately on the documentclass ... you did not show any line of code, however, but `\usepackage[nottoc,notlof,notlot,chapter]{tocbibind}` could help, in conjunction with `\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}` just before `\listoffigures\listoftables` and `\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\arabic{chapter}}` after...

Comment: Please note that your require might cause inconsistent numbering, however

Comment: I was using the report document class. I doubt including any code would help (I just have the table of contents and the figure listing initiated, I didn't do anything else to them), besides, it is pretty messy.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Don't those commands just change the numbering of the chapters? The Table of Contents and the List of Figures, remain unnumbered.

Answer (score 2):

By default `\tableofcontents` and `\listoffigures` do not use numbered headings. This can be changed using the `tocbibind` package.

The following code redefines `\tableofcontents` and inserts the `\tocchapter` instruction, then loading the `.toc` file with `\tocfile{\contentsname}{toc}`.

The macro `\unboldchapternumber` defines the chapter number to be not bold and switches to `\Roman` and redefines the potential hyper anchor `\theHchapter` in case of `hyperref` being loaded.

```
  \renewcommand{\tableofcontents}{%
    \begingroup
    \unboldchapternumber%
    \tocchapter
    \tocfile{\contentsname}{toc}
    \endgroup
  }
```

After loading `\listoffigures`, the chapter counter should be reset to zero.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newif\ifhyperrefloaded
% Check whether hyperref is loaded
\@ifpackageloaded{hyperref}{
  \hyperrefloadedtrue
}{}
\makeatother


\newcommand{\unboldchapternumber}{%
  \renewcommand{\thechapter}{\normalfont\Roman{chapter}\bfseries}%
  \ifhyperrefloaded
  % Change the hyperanchors to prevent wrong anchors
  \renewcommand{\theHchapter}{tocchapter.\arabic{chapter}}%
  \fi
}

  \renewcommand{\tableofcontents}{%
    \begingroup
    \unboldchapternumber%
    \tocchapter
    \tocfile{\contentsname}{toc}
    \endgroup
  }
  \renewcommand{\listoffigures}{%
    \begingroup
    \unboldchapternumber
    \tocchapter
    \tocfile{\listfigurename}{lof}
    \endgroup
  }

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures

\setcounter{chapter}{0}
\chapter{One}

\blindtext

\chapter{Two}

\blindtext
\end{document}
```